# what is my openssl and ssl Default CA Certs Path?

Tags: python, ssl, https, openssl, tls1.2

**Background :**

I am trying to create an SSL context connection with an external vendor for handshake and then communicate using an xml over that connection.

```
clientCert = path["cert_path"]
clientKey = path["key_path"]
PROTOCOL = ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1
context = ssl.SSLContext(PROTOCOL)
context.load_default_certs()
context.load_cert_chain(clientCert, clientKey)
conn = httplib.HTTPSConnection(uri, 443, context=context) 
conn.request("POST", '/', headers=headers, body=signedRequest) # code breaks here
response = conn.getresponse()
```

But this code breaks saying :

```
SSLError(1, u'[SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_UNKNOWN_CA] tlsv1 alert unknown ca (_ssl.c:590)
```

Now, I know that the CA certificates are correctly placed on server, somewhere the path is getting messed up.

**Question**

How can i see what is the CA Path from which this `ssl` and `openssl` pick the CA Certs from.
Openssl seems to be making correct connection, so i need to provide the path to ssl explicitly here.

`requests.utils` path can be found up as below, looking for something similar to understand for `context.load_default_certs()`

```
In [1]: from requests.utils import DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH

In [2]: print(DEFAULT_CA_BUNDLE_PATH)
/usr/local/python/path/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem
```

Answer (score 19, accepted):

ok...found it :

command would be `openssl  version -a`

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ openssl  version -a
OpenSSL 1.0.1e-fips 11 Feb 2013
built on: Thu Jul 23 19:06:35 UTC 2015
platform: linux-x86_64
options:  bn(64,64) md2(int) rc4(16x,int) des(idx,cisc,16,int) idea(int) blowfish(idx)
compiler: gcc -fPIC -DOPENSSL_PIC -DZLIB -DOPENSSL_THREADS -D_REENTRANT -DDSO_DLFCN -DHAVE_DLFCN_H -DKRB5_MIT -m64 -DL_ENDIAN -DTERMIO -Wall -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -m64 -mtune=generic -Wa,--noexecstack -DPURIFY -DOPENSSL_IA32_SSE2 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_MONT5 -DOPENSSL_BN_ASM_GF2m -DSHA1_ASM -DSHA256_ASM -DSHA512_ASM -DMD5_ASM -DAES_ASM -DVPAES_ASM -DBSAES_ASM -DWHIRLPOOL_ASM -DGHASH_ASM
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
engines:  rdrand dynamic
```

There would be a value `OPENSSLDIR` in output, this would be the *base path*

```
OPENSSLDIR: "/etc/pki/tls"
```

Most of the cases, this would be a symlink, use `ls -la` to this `OPENSSLDIR` path

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ ls -la /etc/pki/tls
total 32
drwxr-xr-x.  5 root root  4096 Apr  6 10:09 .
drwxr-xr-x. 11 root root  4096 Apr  4 08:47 ..
lrwxrwxrwx   1 root root    19 Apr  6 10:09 cert.pem -> certs/ca-bundle.crt
drwxr-xr-x.  4 root root  4096 Mar 22 18:15 certs
```

Further `ls -la`

```
[someone@somewhere ~]$ ls -la /etc/pki/tls/certs/
total 1908
drwxr-xr-x. 4 root   root      4096 Mar 22 18:15 .
drwxr-xr-x. 5 root   root      4096 Apr  6 10:09 ..
lrwxrwxrwx  1 root   root        49 Apr  6 09:54 ca-bundle.crt -> /etc/pki/ca-trust/some/path/of/cert/tls-ca-bundle.pem
```

and you get the actual path :

```
/etc/pki/ca-trust/some/path/of/cert/tls-ca-bundle.pem
```

Comment: so is `ca-bundle.crt` a key word to OPENSSL or python ssl ? sounds like got a `OPENSSLDIR` from openssl then seek for `certs`, then `ca-bundle.crt`

Comment: symlink to OPENSSL