# Alexa request validation in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, alexa-skills-kit, pyopenssl, alexa-voice-service

I work on a service that will handle Alexa voice intents. I need to verify the signature of each request and I almost succeed. The only part that is not working is the validation of certificates chain.

From the [documentation](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/developing-an-alexa-skill-as-a-web-service#checking-the-signature-of-the-request) I know that:

> This certificate chain is composed of, in order, (1) the Amazon signing 
>   certificate and (2) one or more additional certificates that create a chain of 
>   trust to a root certificate authority (CA) certificate.

My code looks like this:

```
certificates = pem.parse_file("chain.pem")
store = crypto.X509Store()
for cert in certificates[:-1]:
    loaded_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
                                          cert.as_bytes())
    store.add_cert(loaded_cert)

intermediate_cert = crypto.load_certificate(
    crypto.FILETYPE_PEM,
    certificates[-1].as_bytes()
)
# Create a certificate context
store_ctx = crypto.X509StoreContext(store, intermediate_cert)

# Verify the certificate
store_ctx.verify_certificate()
```

I receive the following error:

```
OpenSSL.crypto.X509StoreContextError: [20, 0, 'unable to get local issuer certificate']
```

I don't know what I did wrong, maybe there is someone who already implemented this and can drop a hint.

Comment: Do you have the CA certificate?

Comment: No. I don't know where to get it.

Comment: @VitalieMaldur You can try https://letsencrypt.org/ for certificates

Comment: @stovfl I use `pyopenssl==17.0.0` and `openssl version` command returns `OpenSSL 0.9.8zh 14 Jan 2016
`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First and once get the CA Issuer for **all** Certificate in `'chain.pem'`:

```
for cert in pem.parse_file("chain.pem"):
    CA_cert = crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert.as_bytes())
    print('CA_cert:\nissuer :{}\nsubject:{}'.
        format(CA_cert.get_subject(), CA_cert.get_issuer()))
```

> **Output**, for example:
>
> > ```
> > CA_cert:
> > issuer :<X509Name object '/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA'>
> > subject:<X509Name object '/C=US/O=thawte, Inc./OU=Certification Services Division/OU=(c) 2006 thawte, Inc. - For authorized use only/CN=thawte Primary Root CA'>
> > ```
>
> This shown example Certificate is a *self signed certificate*.

---

Add **all** shown *issuer* to `CA_store`, then do `.verify_certificate` for **all** Certificate in `'chain.pem'`.

```
CA_store = crypto.X509Store()
for _pem in ['issuer_1.pem', 'issuer_2.pem']:
    for cert in pem.parse_file(_pem):
        CA_store.add_cert(
            crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert.as_bytes())
        )

for cert in pem.parse_file("chain.pem"):
    try:
        crypto.X509StoreContext(CA_store,
                                crypto.load_certificate(crypto.FILETYPE_PEM, cert.as_bytes())
                                ).verify_certificate()
    except X509StoreContextError as exp:
        cert = exp.certificate
        print('X509StoreContextError:{}\ncertificate\n\tissuer :{}\n\tsubject:{}'.
            format(exp.args, cert.get_issuer(), cert.get_subject()))
```

***Tested with Python:3.4.2 - OpenSSL:17.0.0 - cryptography:1.8.2 - cffi:1.10.0***

Answer (score 0):

According to [OpenSSL.crypto.X509Store documentation](https://pyopenssl.org/en/stable/api/crypto.html#OpenSSL.crypto.X509Store),

> An X.509 store, being only a description, cannot be used by itself to verify a certificate. To carry out the actual verification process, see X509StoreContext.

So you need at least to include in your store a set of certificates to trust first, then initialise you storecontext and after that you can do the verification job.

You can see more information [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36449336/what-is-my-openssl-and-ssl-default-ca-certs-path) to get the actual path (on which set of certificate to trust are stored.)